# How to read property from OSGI configuration in AEM 6.1 in model class which extends WCMUse class

Tags: osgi, aem

I am extending my model class to WCMUse class to write my business logic. I have osgi configuration which has couple of properties. I want to read one of the property in my model class. I am not sure how to get the handle of osgi configuration in WCMUse class. Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `getSlingScriptHelper().getService(<<Configuration Service>>.class);`

Comment: Thanks, It works!! Highly appreciating...

Comment: Here's another way of doing it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751407/how-can-single-instance-of-an-osgi-factory-configuration-be-read-from-java-in-cq/32659121#32659121

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer for future references.

You can use the `#getSlingScriptHelper()` method of the `WCMUse` class to get an handle of the [SlingScriptHelper](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/scripting/SlingScriptHelper.html). This is the same `sling` object that is available through inclusion of `global.jsp` in traditional JSP scripts.

You can then call `#getService()` method of the SlingScriptHelper to look up the desired OSGi Service.

The following code snippet can be used in the model to get the service configuration

`getSlingScriptHelper().getService(<<Configuration Service>>.class)`